# Everytime I want to display one default value at the end of autocomplete search list irrespective of search results. Can anyone help me in this?

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I have JSON data in my test.php file which I am displaying in the search results of a jQuery AutoComplete control.

Every time I want to display one default value (which is also present in the JSON data) at the end of AutoComplete options list, irrespective of the search results. Can anyone help me in this?

```js
$.getJSON("test.php", function(data) {
  var newData = [];

  $.each(data, function(i) {
    newData.push({
      value: data[i].Id,
      label: data[i].Name
    });
  });

  data2 = JSON.stringify(newData);

  $('#Major').autocomplete({
    minLength: 2,
    source: function(request, response) {
      var q = request.term;
      var myResponse = [];
      $.each(JSON.parse(data2), function(key, item) {
        if (item.label.toLowerCase().indexOf(q) === 0) {
          myResponse.push(item);
        }
      });
      response(myResponse);
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just `push()` the default item to the end of the array once the AJAX call completes. Also note that you can improve your code by using `map()` and `filter()` instead of explicit loops, and also you don't need to stringify and then re-parse the JSON, that's just redundant. Try this:

```js
$.getJSON("test.php", function(data) {
  var newData = data.map(item => {
    value: item.Id,
    label: item.Name
  });

  // add your default here...
  newData.push({
    value: 'foo',
    label: 'bar'
  });

  $('#Major').autocomplete({
    minLength: 2,
    source: function(request, response) {
      var myResponse = newData.filter(item => item.label.toLowerCase().indexOf(request.term) === 0);
      response(myResponse);
    }
  });
});
```